# Create a Day Wise KPI Trend In Excel Using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, trend

I have a Dataframe which looks like this:

[image: Sample Input DataFrame]

```
Period start time Segment Name  KPI_1  KPI_2
       04.13.2023      AI4301A  51.49   3.85
       04.13.2023      AI4301B 193.79   1.56
       04.13.2023      AI4301C  95.69   1.25
       04.14.2023      AI4301A  59.47   2.42
       04.14.2023      AI4301B 193.11   1.32
       04.14.2023      AI4301C  81.90   1.94
       04.15.2023      AI4301A  46.73   3.11
       04.15.2023      AI4301B 179.33   1.47
       04.15.2023      AI4301C  78.95   1.51
```

I want the Output to be like this without any empty row between the Segment Name Rows & AI4301A:

[image: Output Dataframe]

```
       |           KPI_1                |            KPI_2            |
Segment Name 04.13.2023 04.14.2023  04.15.2023  04.13.2023  04.14.2023  04.15.2023
AI4301A         51.49   59.47           46.73   3.85        2.42            3.11
AI4301B         193.79  193.11          179.33  1.56        1.32            1.47
AI4301C         95.69   81.90           78.95   1.25        1.94            1.51
```

I should be able to add as many KPIs, Segment Name and  Period start time as I want which gives above similar pattern

What I have tried so far:

`df =(df.groupby(['Segment Name', pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='Period start time')]) ['Segment Name','KPI_1','KPI_2'] .sum() .unstack())`

I am getting the output as follows :

```
                KPI_1                               KPI_2       
Segment Name    04.13.2023  04.14.2023  04.15.2023  04.13.2023  04.14.2023  04.15.2023
                        
AI4301A             51.49   59.47           46.73       3.85        2.42    3.11
AI4301B             193.79  193.11          179.33      1.56        1.32    1.47
AI4301C             95.69   81.90           78.95       1.25        1.94    1.51
```

The Problem is that after applying the above code neither i am not able to remove the blank row after the Header row nor able to perform any operation like merge another dataframe based on Segment Name.
Please help Experts

***Edit:***
Adding the Dataframe to be merged:

```
segmentName ID_1    ID_2
AI4301A     AI_05   2741
AI4301B     AI_05   2742
AI4301C     AI_05   2743
```

[image: Final Desired Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your first question (*while building on top of @[Corralien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien)'s answer*), you can use this :

```
#from @Corralien's answer + joining the 2nd dataframe
out = (df1.rename(columns={"KPI_1": "Sum of KPI_1", "KPI_2": "Sum of KPI_2"})
         .pivot_table(index="Segment Name", columns="Period start time",
                      values=["Sum of KPI_1", "Sum of KPI_2"], aggfunc="sum")
         .join(df2.set_index("segmentName").set_axis(
                pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[''], df2.columns[1:]]), axis=1))
         .set_index([("", "ID_1"), ("", "ID_2")], append=True)
         .rename_axis(index=lambda x: x[1] if isinstance(x, tuple) else x)
         .reset_index()
 
      )

#making/formatting the spreadsheet
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    out.loc[:-1].to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1") #the shape
    (out.style.set_properties(**{"border":"1px solid black"})
         .to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=1, header=False)) #the data
     
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
     
    worksheet.set_column("A:A", None, None, {"hidden": True}) #to hide the index column
    
    lvl0_format = workbook.add_format(
        {"bold": True, "border": 1, "bg_color": "#dce6f1", "align": "center"}
    )
    for tup in [(idx_col, col_name) for idx_col, col_name
                in enumerate(out.columns.get_level_values(0))][3::3]:
        worksheet.write(0, tup[0]+1, tup[1], lvl0_format)

    lvl1_format = workbook.add_format(
        {"bold": True, "border": 1, "bg_color": "#dce6f1", "rotation": 90}
    )
    for idx_col, col_name in enumerate(out.columns.get_level_values(1)[1:]):
        worksheet.write(1, idx_col+2, col_name, lvl1_format)
            
    white_format = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "white"})
    sgn_format = workbook.add_format(
        {"bold": True, "bg_color": "#124191", "color": "white", "border": 1}
    )
    ids_format = workbook.add_format(
        {
            "bold": True, "bg_color": "#0070c0", "color": "white",
             "border": 1, "valign": "vcenter", "align": "center"
        }
    )
    for tup in [(idx_col, col_name) for idx_col, col_name
            in enumerate(out.columns.get_level_values(0))][:3]:
        worksheet.write(0, tup[0]+1, None, white_format)
        if tup[1] == "Segment Name":
            worksheet.write(1, tup[0]+1, tup[1], sgn_format)
        else:
            worksheet.write(1, tup[0]+1, tup[1], ids_format)

    worksheet.autofit()
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Timeless and Corralien. Problem is resolved with your support

Comment: Accepted @Corralien's answer. Can anyone please help me with the 2nd question. How would I perform merge operation on the out dataframe?

Comment: You need to share an example of the other dataframe and show the exact matching output.

Comment: Thanks @Timeless I've added the examples of the 2nd dataframe and the desired output. Kindly help

Comment: Assuming the segment names are unique in `df2`, I updated my answer. You can check it out!

Comment: Note that you can merge `df1` and `df2` before the pivot and then slightly re-adjust my previous [code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/bdf2f2ef-e047-4b2d-b87b-ed587c563cbb/view-source).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index='Segment Name', columns='Period start time',
                      values=['KPI_1', 'KPI_2'], aggfunc='sum')
         .rename_axis(columns=[None, None]))
print(out)

# Output
                  KPI_1                            KPI_2                      
             04.13.2023 04.14.2023 04.15.2023 04.13.2023 04.14.2023 04.15.2023
Segment Name                                                                  
AI4301A           51.49      59.47      46.73       3.85       2.42       3.11
AI4301B          193.79     193.11     179.33       1.56       1.32       1.47
AI4301C           95.69      81.90      78.95       1.25       1.94       1.51
```

To go further:

```
out.index.name = ('', 'Segment Name')
out = out.reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
                    KPI_1                            KPI_2                      
  Segment Name 04.13.2023 04.14.2023 04.15.2023 04.13.2023 04.14.2023 04.15.2023
0      AI4301A      51.49      59.47      46.73       3.85       2.42       3.11
1      AI4301B     193.79     193.11     179.33       1.56       1.32       1.47
2      AI4301C      95.69      81.90      78.95       1.25       1.94       1.51
```

**One-liner**:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index='Segment Name', columns='Period start time',
                      values=['KPI_1', 'KPI_2'], aggfunc='sum')
         .rename_axis(index=[('', 'Segment Name')], columns=[None, None])
         .reset_index())
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien for your response. But when I try to export the output data frame to excel i am still getting blank row after header rows. Also please suggest how to convert this to a normal dataframe so that i can further perform "merge" operations on 'Segment Name"

Comment: @Timeless Can you please modify the above code so that I can sort the columns as per my requirement?